# Segmentation fault in passing pointer to a linked list

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Hello fellow programmers, the below code gives segmentation fault. This code aims to insert an element at the end of a linked list. I tried using print statements to debug it. I think the error is in passing the linked list pointer to insert() function. Please tell me how can I correct it. Thanks in advance.

Below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node {
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node(int data) {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = NULL;
    } 
};

class linked_list {
public: 
    node *head;
    linked_list() {
        this->head = NULL;
    }
};

void insert(node **head, int data);
void print(linked_list *L);

int main() {
    int N;
    linked_list *A = new linked_list();
    
    cout << "N: ";
    cin >> N;
    for(int i=0; i<=N-1; i++) {
        int t;
        cin >> t;
        insert(&(A->head), t);
    }
    print(A);
    return 0;
}

void insert(node **head, int data) {
    node *temp = new node(data);
    if(*head == NULL) {
        *head = temp;
        return;
    } else {
        node *t = *head;
        while(t->next != NULL) {
            t=t->next;
        }
        t->next = temp;
        return;
    }
}

void print(linked_list *L) {
    node * t = L->head;
    while(t!=NULL) {
        cout << t->data << " ";
        t = t->next;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend making insert and print functions of linked_list. Then you could simply call A->insert(t);, and insert could access this->head.

Comment: When I compiled your code, I noticed that you must not have compiler warnings enabled.  I strongly recommend that you enable your compiler warnings.  Most compilers can do static analysis for common coding mistakes, much like the old **lint** tool used to do (but now built into the compiler).

Comment: Got to ask why you are doing this `linked_list *A = new linked_list();` instead of the simpler, more efficient, more obvious etc etc `linked_list A;` Pointers are not compulsory.

Comment: Also `insert` (and maybe `print`) should be methods of your `linked_list` class, not free functions. Maybe you're just getting round to that.

Answer (score 2):

```
main.cpp:42:14: error: using the result of an assignment as a
      condition without parentheses [-Werror,-Wparentheses]
    if(*head = NULL) {
       ~~~~~~^~~~~~
main.cpp:42:14: note: place parentheses around the assignment to
      silence this warning
    if(*head = NULL) {
             ^
       (           )
main.cpp:42:14: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an
      equality comparison
    if(*head = NULL) {
             ^
             ==
1 error generated.
```

You're using assignment where you intended to do a comparison.

Comment: And this is the reason why i always make my checks like so: `if(NULL == *head)` (const value first, before non-const value)